# unsure of owncloud mysql password and database

Tags: mysql, owncloud-server

I've recently attempted to make my pc an owncloud server. I attempted to logon on the same machine I am hosting it on. However, I first need to enter a mysql password, database name, etc., and I don't know any details. how can I find this out?

Answer (score 0):

The ownCloud installation requires access to a database such as MySQL on the server it is running on, in your case this is your PC.

When you install MySQL, you become the MySQL `root` and have to create a new database, which you give the name and password to be used by ownCloud.

This should get you started:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

As far as I remember, this will let you set a password for your MySQL `root` user. Then log on to MySQL like so:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Which will ask you for the password you've given in the first step. On the MySQL prompt, create a database (I named it `owncloud`) and switch to using it

```
CREATE DATABASE owncloud;
USE owncloud;
```

Then create a user and password to access the `owncloud` database and exit MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON owncloud.* TO myocuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mysupersecretpassword';
EXIT
```

Using this example, the user and password for the MySQL database you have to enter at the ownCloud installation are `myocuser` and `mysupersecretpassword`, respectively (which you should change for your installation, of course).